# Check internet connection with 3G and Wifi in Android

Tags: android, networking

Sometimes, I have to check internet connection in my android app:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

The code above only work when one `Network` available! However, my Device has `wifi` and `3G`, the code above always return `false` when I use both 2 type of network connection above! (I still can use `google.com` when It return `false`)!! What did I miss? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone, tomorrow I will check it!! Thanks for replying me!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() 
{
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
    {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this code?

```
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    // Check the current state of the Network Information
    if (networkInfo == null)
        return false;
    if (networkInfo.isConnected() == false)
        return false;
    if (networkInfo.isAvailable() == false)
        return false;
    return true;
```

Remember to add this in your application manifest file also :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`